# What do Affinity Designer’s four stroke dash values mean?

Tags: stroke, affinity-designer

In Affinity Designer 1.10.6, Stroke studio, I can choose Dash Line Style, and then four numbers for Dash. But the four numbers aren’t labeled, and no tooltip shows upon hover. The online documentation (https://affinity.help/designer/en-US.lproj/index.html?page=pages/Panels/strokePanel.html?title=Stroke%20panel) says “this option allows you to set the design of the dot or dash (see below for details)”, but that appears nearly at the bottom of the page, and no details appear below it.

Comment: This is not exclusive to Affinity Designer. Other vector and pixel softwares have the same function as well, which is kinda neat and useful! (And they usually don't have it labeled as well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The 4 unknown numbers are segment lengths, their unit is one stroke width.

I have 1 W(idth) first dash, 2 W first gap, 4 W second dash and 8 W second gap.

The phase means how many widths the pattern is shifted towards to the start of the curve. My example has no shift. In the next image the shift is 3 widths:

[image]

Name phase is not a common drawing term. The programmer has obviously picked it from the electric signal theory terminology.

Comment: Thank you especially for explaining the unit value.